# How to push data to a child element

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I need to push data to a child element.Is it possible to start a new node at the 'model' node.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
   usernames = database.child("Item_features").get()
   for user in usernames.each():
       userid = user.key()
       dtls =    database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child('model').get().val()
       if dtls == imodel:
           data = {"left": left}        
       database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child('model'),child("left").push(data)
           data = {"right": right}
        database.child("Item_features").child(userid).child('model').child("right").push(data)
```

Comment: You have a `,` in here: `child('model'),child("left")`. Is that intentional, or should it be a `.`?

Comment: hey , thanks it is working now

Comment: Good to hear Mia. I'm voting to close this question as a typo then, since it's unlikely that folks caught in the same situation will find it.

Comment: Okay , I am sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: No need to be sorry, we're here to help.